# RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0

Tags: git, github

When I am trying to push my WordPress project to GitHub I got this **error**

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL 
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it worked after removing an audio file i was testing on.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The message "bad record mac" means that the MAC, or message authentication code, protecting your connection from tampering failed.  In other words, your connection has been corrupted or tampered with, either intentionally or unintentionally.  When this happens, the only thing to do is drop the connection.

It's likely that you have some sort of network problem.  That could be a flaky connection (maybe your ISP is having problems), a proxy, an antivirus software, or a third-party firewall.  It is possible but extremely unlikely that GitHub is having an issue.

If you are using a proxy, try moving to another network.  If you're using a third-party antivirus or firewall, try completely uninstalling it and restarting.  You could also check various websites to see if your ISP is having problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it happened to me because of poor internet connection, I checked it after reading your answer.